# How do I get the files in a directory and all of its subdirectories in bash?

Tags: bash, gcc, makefile, kernel

I'm working on a C kernel and I want to make it easier to compile all of the sources by using a bash script file. I need to know how to do a foreach loop and only get the files with a .c extension, and then get the filename of each file I find so I can make gcc compile each one.

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` to walk through your tree
and then read the list it generates using `while read`:

```
find . -name \*.c | while read file
do
 echo process $file
done
```

If the action that you want to do with file is not so complex
and can be expressed using ore or two commands, you can avoid `while`
and make all things with the `find` itself. For that you will use `-exec`:

```
find . -name \*.c -exec command {} \;
```

Here you write your command instead of `command`.

You can also use `-execdir`:

```
find . -name \*.c -execdir command {} \;
```

In this case `command` will be executed in the directory of found file (for each file that was found).

Comment: Should I replace -name with the name of my directory?

Comment: No.  `-name` is an option being passed to the find command that says to search by name.  The `.` represents `the current directory`, so you should either run this command from the project root or replace the `.` with the path to the project root.  The `*.c` means files whose name matches `anthing followed by .c`.  So if your project is in /foo/bar and you want to find .h files, use the following: `find /foo/bar -name *.h`

Comment: @jahroy: thank you jahroy, that is exactly I wanted to say :)

Comment: @user1547531 - Make sure you select this answer as the solution if it solved your problem

Comment: @IgorChubin Why not `-exec` or `-execdir`?

Comment: @Bernhard: added explanation of `-exec` and `-execdir` to the answer. thank you very much for the hint

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `GNU make`, you can do this using only `make`'s built-in functions, which has the advantage of making it independent of the shell (but the disadvantage of being slower than `find` for large trees):

```
# Usage: $(call find-recursive,DIRECTORY,PATTERN)
find-recursive = \
  $(foreach f,$(wildcard $(1)/*),\
    $(if $(wildcard $(f)/.),\
      $(call find-recursive,$(f),$(2)),\
      $(filter $(2),$(f))))

all:
     @echo $(call find-recursive,.,%.c)
```